# install PyTorch CPU-only in Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pytorch, dockerfile, python-poetry

I am fairly new to **Docker** and containerisation. I am wanting to decrease the size of `my_proj` docker container in production.

I prefer installing packages and managing dependencies via `Poetry`.

How can I specify using **CPU-only** `PyTorch` in a `Dockerfile`?

To do this via. `bash` terminal, it would be:

```
poetry add pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

(or `conda install`...)

---

My existing `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as base
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install curl wget\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
ENV ROOT /home/worker/python/my_proj
WORKDIR $ROOT

ARG ATLASSIAN_TOKEN
ARG POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_AZURE_PASSWORD
ARG ACCESS_KEY
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$ACCESS_KEY
ARG SECRET_KEY
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$SECRET_KEY
ARG REPO
ENV REPO_URL=$REPO
ENV PYPIRC_PATH=$ROOT/.pypirc

ENV \
    PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.4 \
    POETRY_HOME=/etc/poetry \
    XDG_CACHE_HOME=/home/worker/.cache \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    MPLCONFIGDIR=/home/worker/matplotlib \
    PATH=/home/worker/python/my_proj/.venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/etc/poetry/bin:$PATH

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py ./
RUN python get-poetry.py && chmod +x /etc/poetry/bin/poetry
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache apt update && apt install gcc -y

FROM base as ws
ARG WS_APIKEY
ARG WS_PROJECTVERSION=
ARG WS_PROJECTNAME=workers-python-my_proj
ARG WS_PRODUCTNAME=HALO
COPY --chown=worker:worker . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,uid=1000,target=/home/worker/.cache poetry install --no-dev
COPY --from=openjdk:15-slim-buster /usr/local/openjdk-15 /usr/local/openjdk-15
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/openjdk-15
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN --mount=type=cache,uid=1000,target=/home/worker/.cache ./wss_agent.sh

FROM base as test
COPY . .
RUN poetry config experimental.new-installer false
RUN poetry install
RUN cd my_proj && poetry run invoke deployconfluence_server_pass=$ATLASSIAN_TOKEN

FROM base as package
COPY . .
RUN poetry build
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
pip install twine keyring artifacts-keyring && \
twine upload -r $REPO_URL --config-file $PYPIRC_PATH dist/* --skip-existing

FROM base as build
COPY . .
RUN poetry config experimental.new-installer false
RUN poetry install --no-dev
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli
RUN aws s3 cp s3://....tar.gz $ROOT/my_proj # censored url
RUN mkdir $ROOT/my_proj/bert-base-cased && cd $ROOT/my_proj/bert-base-cased && \
wget https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/resolve/main/config.json && \
wget https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/resolve/main/tokenizer.json && \
wget https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json 

FROM python:3.7-slim as production
ENV  ROOT=/home/worker/python/my_proj \
     VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/worker/python/my_proj/.venv\
     PATH=/home/worker/python/my_proj/.venv/bin:/home/worker/python/my_proj:$PATH
COPY --from=build /home/worker/python/my_proj/pyproject.toml /home/worker/python/
COPY --from=build /home/worker/python/my_proj/.venv /home/worker/python/my_proj/.venv
COPY --from=build /home/worker/python/my_proj/my_proj /home/worker/python/my_proj
WORKDIR $ROOT
ENV PYTHONPATH=$ROOT:/home/worker/python/
ENTRYPOINT [ "primary_worker", "--mongo" ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing it via pip should work:

```
RUN pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cpu torchvision==0.10.0+cpu torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: Is there a way I can "test run" a `Dockerfile`? In an isolated environment, like locally on my machine or on a website?

Comment: What line number should I insert/ replace this on/ with?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to install via `pip` in case you're experiencing `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement / ERROR: No matching distribution found`:

```
RUN pip install torch==2.0.0 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```